# A better way to do this query in PL/pgSQL

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, plpgsql

I am trying to turn the following query from Transact-SQL to PL/pgSQL

```
SELECT @val1 = val1, @val2= val2 FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE val3 = @val3
```

This with I have come out:

```
v_val1 := val1 FROM MyTable WHERE val3  = v_val3;
v_val2 := val2 FROM MyTable WHERE val3 = v_val3;
```

Is there a better way to do this? May be in the same sentence like Transact-SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select val1, val2 into v_val1, v_val2 
from mytable 
where val3 = v_val3
```

Comment: Makes it even look simpler!

Comment: Thanks, looks elegant and helped me improve the performance of a postgres function.